# What is the ARMCC compiler option for automatic insertion of prefetching instructions during compilation process?

Tags: arm, compiler-optimization, armcc

I'm trying to evaluate the gain if I insert prefetching instructions manually into a source code and when I order the compiler ARMCC to insert that prefetching instructions automatically. But I don't know the compilation option (command-line) that orders ARMCC compiler to insert prefetching instructions automatically during the compilation process. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

They are under documentation topic [Chapter 10 Compiler-specific Features](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472l/chr1359124998581.html)

[`__pld`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472l/chr1359124998581.html): This intrinsic inserts a data prefetch, for example PLD, into the instruction stream generated by the compiler. It enables you to signal to the memory system from your C or C++ program that a data load from an address is likely in the near future.

[`__pldw`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472l/chr1359124998815.html): This intrinsic inserts a PLDW instruction into the instruction stream generated by the compiler. It enables you to signal to the memory system from your C or C++ program that a data load from an address with an intention to write is likely in the near future.
This intrinsic inserts a PLDW instruction into the instruction stream generated by the compiler. It enables you to signal to the memory system from your C or C++ program that a data load from an address with an intention to write is likely in the near future.

[`__pli`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472l/chr1359124999080.html): This intrinsic inserts an instruction prefetch, for example PLI, into the instruction stream generated by the compiler. It enables you to signal to the memory system from your C or C++ program that an instruction load from an address is likely in the near future.

Comment: Thanks @auselen I'm aware of that and I've used that intrinsic to insert data prefetching instructions manually into my source code and ARMCC generated PLD accordingly. But, what I request is to know the option to pass into the command-line of ARMCC compiler (as with gcc ...  --fprefetch-loop-arrays) to order ARMCC compiler to add PLD into the instruction stream generated. My goal is to compare what ARMCC does to what I'm doing.